# How to solve: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Im trying to use Stack navigator in react native in order to go from my "welcome screen" to my next page, "create alarm screen" However, it keeps giving me the error that navigation.navigate is undefined.

I created a MyStack function in an index.js file:

```html
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='WelcomeScreen'>
      <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="CreateAlarmScreen" component={CreateAlarmScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MyStack;
```

This is my WelcomeScreen.js file:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions,Button, Text, View ,TouchableOpacity, Image, SafeAreaView, Component } from 'react-native';
import { backgroundColor } from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ReactNativeStyleAttributes';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';



function WelcomeScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style= {styles.Container}>
            <View style={styles.CreateAlarmButton}>
                <Button 
                onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('CreateAlarmScreen')}
                title='Create an Alarm'
                color="white"
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.ViewAlarmButton}>
                <Button 
                title='View Alarms'
                color="black"
        
                />
            </View>
            
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
export default WelcomeScreen;
```

and then this is my app.js file:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text, View ,TouchableOpacity, Image, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import WelcomeScreen from './app/screens/WelcomeScreen';
import CreateAlarmScreen from './app/screens/CreateAlarmScreen';
import MyStack from './app/Navigation';

export default function App() {

  

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack/>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'peachpuff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
    
  },
});
```

I really confused on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Strange, from what I see, I don't see anything wrong. You can also try using the `useNavigation` hook inside WelcomeScreen. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/

Comment: @JordanDaniels When I do this then it gives me the "Render Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?"

Comment: Can you try `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';` instead of `import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/

Answer (score 0):

you can import use navigation, and then you can declare that variable

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Comment: When I do this then it gives me the "Render Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?"

Answer (score -1):

`navigation` is often populated after the first render, so it will be undefined until it populates. Try `navigation?.navigate` instead.

Comment: Doing this does not solve the issue

Comment: You get the same error?